# Is right this application of Hadamard three-lines theorem for $ \frac{\zeta(s)}{s}- \frac{d\zeta(s)}{d\sigma}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, riemann-zeta

Let the complex variable $s=\sigma+it$, then from the following identity valid  for $\sigma=\Re s>1$
$$\zeta(s)=s\int_1^\infty \frac{[x]}{x^{s+1}}dx$$
where $\zeta(s)$ is the **Riemann Zeta function**, 
I've computed by differentition under the integral sign 
$$ \frac{\zeta(s)}{s}- \frac{d\zeta(s)}{d\sigma} =s(\sigma+1)\int_1^\infty\frac{[x]\log x}{x^{\sigma+2}}e^{-it\log x} dx.$$

I don't know if my deduction was right, and I believe that previous makes sense for $\sigma>2$, and on the strip $ \left\{ x+iy:a\leq x\leq b \right\} $ thus with $a>2$, since $\frac{\zeta(s)}{s}- \frac{d\zeta(s)}{d\sigma}$ is a bounded function of $s$ defined on the strip, holomorphic in the interior of the strip and continuous on the whole strip, defining $$M(x)=\sup_y \left| \frac{\zeta(x+iy)}{x+iy}- \frac{d\zeta(x+iy)}{dx} \right| ,$$
the [Hadamard three-lines theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-lines_theorem) proves that $\log M(x)$ is a convex function on  $\left[ a,b \right]$ (here as I've said $a>2$).

> **Question.** Were rights, do make sense all my claims looking a simple application of the Hadamard three-lines theorem for a function on a strip to the right of $\sigma>2$? **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If there are no mistakes, I know by comments from an user in this site, that derivation under the integral sign should be justified since everything converges absolutely, writing the limit defining the derivative explicity, but I would like see details to learn these appreciated computations.

Comment: there is a big problem with your "derivative" : $\frac{d\zeta(s)}{ds} = \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1} dx + \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1} (\ln x) dx$. did you understand the derivatives of holomorphic/analytic functions, the Cauchy-Riemann equations ?  and $a > 1$ is enough for applying Hadamard's 3 lines theorem

Comment: I think I've understood the basics of the theory of derivatives of analytic functions , but not from the point of view to put in practice satisfactorily, so I try to get my hands simple examples to refresh and learn what are my mistakes. I don't know why $a>1$ is suffcient. Then I am agree that my computations are wrong or aren't the best. Thanks @user1952009

Comment: Currently, I don't know how get your derivative @user1952009 with respect the complex variable, thus I am agree that I don't understand the theory. Thanks.

Comment: there is a typo, I forgot a $s$ term : $\zeta'(s) = (s\int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1} dx)' = \int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1} dx + s\int_1^\infty \lfloor x \rfloor x^{-s-1} (\ln x) dx$

Comment: and what you didn't understand is that the derivative of an analytic function is itself analytic, and the [Cauchy Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations)

Comment: Your computation is now the rule for the derivative of a product, and **in the body of my post there is a great mistake since** $$\frac{d}{d\sigma}x^{-\sigma-1}=-x^{-\sigma-2}\log x$$ for $x>1$ **is a false equation**, the right is $$\frac{d}{d\sigma}x^{-\sigma-1}=-x^{-\sigma-1}\log x,$$ and you tell me now that I need verify Cauchy-Riemann equations for the derivative with the purpose to detect mistakes in my computations. Very thanks much, now try do the computations, but I am waiting answers to my bounty, @user1952009

Comment: the right formula is $\frac{d}{ds} x^{-s-1} = - x^{s-1} \log x$ for every $s \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \ne 0$, because $s \to x^{-s-1} = e^{- (s+1) \log x}$ is analytic in $s$, hence we don't need partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial Re(s)}x^{-s-1}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial Im(s)}x^{-s-1}$ because the two are related by a constant factor $i$ (the Cauchy-Riemann equations)

Comment: Perfect explanation, very thanks much. Then I am waiting answer for my bounty, but your explanation is much appreciated @user1952009

Comment: I am sorry @user1952009, but this morning I was thinking about Cauchy Riemann equations and holomorphic functions, and I am asking if it is obvious that $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}$ is holomorphic for the disc $|s|<1$ and if it is possible/has meaning (I am trying prove the equations but the computations are very tedious and I know that the functions has a problem at $s=1$) verify the two Cauchy-Riemann equations for such function $f(s)$. PLease could you say me if it is obvious that the function is holomorphic in the disc?Could say me if I can verify/has meaning CR for the function only in the disc?